# How to deploy MERN stack app to GitHub and Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, heroku, mern

I've been using ReactJS for front-end development for quite a while now a decided I want to upgrade my skill to full-stack with MERN (MongoDB - Express - React - Node). I've successfully developed my MERN app but failed the deployment process.

I was trying to use the "from GitHub to Heroku" method where you first upload everything to GitHub and from there use it on Heroku. I wasn't even able to upload my file structure to GitHub so I'm looking for some help.

I was wondering maybe my file structure is wrong so here are some screenshots so you get the idea:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to upload to GitHub I get this warning:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: client
```

Followed up with bunch of hints... Why is this happening? I think both client and server have separate .gitignore files, might this be the issue?

```
cd (to the directory where client and server are)
git init
git add .
```

At this point I keep getting the warning:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: client
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> client
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached client
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please give a [mre], using **text** not screenshots. Are you trying to deploy one repo or two? One *app* or two?

Comment: I'm trying to upload both files (client and server) to one github repo. Both these files are part of my app - frontend and backend. So I'm trying to deploy only one app.

Comment: I've added some code to the end of my question so you can see what I'm doing

Comment: Well it seems like the client directory is *already* a repo (e.g. Create React App creates one by default). You can have more than one `.gitignore`, that's not a problem, but you'll have to delete `./client/.git/` if you want to have a single repo. Then you'll have the problem that Heroku expects a *root* package file for the Node buildpack. I've put together an example full-stack JS starter that runs on (among other things) Heroku [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit) if you want an example.

Comment: You are right, I used git status command and it seems in my client folder git is already initiated. How can I remove it? I can't see it anywhere, I can somehow cd into it but I can't use rm to remove .git file. Is there any way to stop that repository?

Comment: It's a *directory*, not a file. Beware that you'll lose all your previous commits in the client app if you delete it.

Comment: I haven't committed anything yet, the app is not on GitHub, working on my local host only right now. I will try to remove the directory and upload to GitHub afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted .git file and was able to upload both files to github repo. Now I will try to battle the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used create-react-app. create-react-app also initiates a git repository.

Just delete `./client/.git` and then do it. That should be fine.

```
cd ./client
rm -rf .git
```